# touchesEnded Sound?

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, audio-player, touches

I'm trying to play a sound on touchesEnded but I'm having a problem.  There are multiple objects that get moved around, so if the below code holds true when any object is moved, it constantly plays the sound.  How do I only play it once?

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    if(CGRectContainsRect([image1 frame], [image2 frame])){

        [self playsound];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want it to play for a certain object that calls touchesEnded, you first need to identify that object and then you can just do a quick if-then statement.

If you only want it to play once, then just give it a quick variable like `int playCount = 0;` and then set it to `playCount = 1;` after you're done playing and do an if-then statement on that as well (i.e. play it if playCount is 0, don't play it if playCount is 1).